# Running a single test from a Suite with @ClassRule fails

Tags: java, junit, junit4, testcontainers

To create the environment just once and to avoid inheritance I have defined a JUnit Suite class with a `@ClassRule`:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)               
@Suite.SuiteClasses({               
  SuiteTest1.class              
})      

public class JUnitTest {

    @ClassRule
    private static DockerComposeContainer env = ...


    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

And there's a Test class that uses env in a test method:

```
public class SuiteTest1 {               

    @Test
    public void method(){
        client.query(...);// Executes a query against docker container


    }
}
```

When I execute the tests by running the Test Suite everything works as expected. But when I directly try to run (even with IDE) the `SuiteTest1` test class, it fails and nothing from the Suite is called (i.e. `@`[ClassRule](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/docker_compose.html) and `@BeforeClass`).

Any suggestions on how to achieve also the SuiteTest1 single execution in an good way (without calling static methods of `JUnitTest` from within the `SuiteTest1`) ?

Comment: You have a misconception. The suite will manage the start and stop of the docker container, in your case. However, it will not perform any dependency injection of the `env` variable into your test classes. Further, [any fields annotated with either `@Rule` or `@ClassRule` need to be public](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ClassRule.html) which also only work on subtypes of `TestRule` where I'm not sure if `DockerContainer` is one. As `env` is static already you can access it in your test classes via `JUnitTest.env` after changing it to public, which you have to do anyway.

Comment: Hi @RomanVottner, thanks for your response. The suite starts and stops the container if I run the suite. My question is about running a single test of the suite (like from the IDE): it seems that if I run just a test class, docker containers are not started. Do you know a way to solve both problems:

1- Run once the docker containers per suite
2- Run once the docker containers if I run just one Test

Comment: A test class won't inherit stuff defined in a test suite. It further isn't really aware of being a member of a certain (or multiple) test suites at all. You basically have to create a test-suite for each combination you may want to run then or move the stuff from the suite into the respective test class.

Comment: Ok, but for integration test use case that would mean spin up / tear down a docker environment for each test class... which basically kills the performance of test phase. The goal is to spin up the env once for all test classes, probably I have to raise the scenario to testcontainers

Comment: Either copy your test suite and only add the test classes you want to run in your IDE then or temporary alter your existing testsuite and comment out the classes you don't want to get executed by your IDE. You can also try to run your tests [more programmatically](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java)

Comment: A further way would be to write a test rule that basically does the job of starting and stopping the docker container. You need to do this inside a singleton i.e. and check first if already an instance got created beforehand. This would allow you to define the test rule both in the suite and in the test class. While executing a test suite, the test suite would initialize the container and downstream test classes would ignore the task while executing a single test class would initialize the container as no suite did it before

Comment: Yes I though about that but I did not like the solution a lot. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing the question: you want a JUnit suite with before-all and after-all hooks, which would also run when running the tests one by one (e.g. from an IDE).

AFAIK JUnit 4 provides nothing out-of-the-box for this, but if you're OK with incorporating some Spring third-parties deps ([spring-test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/5.1.2.RELEASE) and [spring-context](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/5.1.2.RELEASE)) into your project I can propose a workaround I've been using.

**Full code example of what follows in this post [can be found here](https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow--spring-boot-test-suite).**

## Solution (using Spring)

We'll use Spring context for implementing our initialization and cleanup. Let's add a base class for our tests:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractTestClass.ContextInitializer.class)
public class AbstractTestClass {
    
    @ClassRule
    public final static SpringClassRule springClassRule = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    public static class ContextInitializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
            System.out.println("Initializing context");

            context.addApplicationListener(
                    (ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>)
                            contextClosedEvent ->
                                    System.out.println("Closing context"));
        }
    }
}
```

Note the [`SpringClassRule`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html) and [`SpringMethodRule`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringMethodRule.html) JUnit rules which enhance our base class with Spring-superpowers (Spring test annotation processing - [`ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) in this case, but there are many more goodies in there - see [Spring testing reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html) for details). You could use [`SpringRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html) for this purpose, but it's a far less flexible solution (thus omitted).

Test classes:

```
public class TestClass1 extends AbstractTestClass {
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("TestClass1 test");
    }
}

public class TestClass2 extends AbstractTestClass {
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("TestClass2 test");
    }
}
```

And the test suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class})
public class TestSuite {
}
```

Output when running the suite (removed Spring-specific logs for brievity):

```
Initializing context
TestClass1 test
TestClass2 test
Closing context
```

Output when running a single test (`TestClass1`):

```
Initializing context
TestClass1 test
Closing context
```

## A word of explanation

The way this works is because of Spring's context caching. Quote from the docs:

> Once the TestContext framework loads an `ApplicationContext` (or `WebApplicationContext`) for a test, that context is cached and reused for all subsequent tests that declare the same unique context configuration within the same test suite. To understand how caching works, it is important to understand what is meant by “unique” and “test suite.”
>
> -- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

Beware that you will get another context (and another initialization) if you override the context configuration (e.g. add another context initializer with `ContextConfiguration`) for any of the classes in the hierarchy (`TestClass1` or `TestClass2` in our example).

## Using beans to share instances

You can define beans in your context. They'll be shared across all tests using the same context. This can be useful for sharing an object across the test suite (a Testcontainers container in your case judging by the tags).

Let's add a bean:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractTestClass.ContextInitializer.class)
public class AbstractTestClass {

    @ClassRule
    public final static SpringClassRule springClassRule = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    public static class ContextInitializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
            ADockerContainer aDockerContainer = new ADockerContainer();
            aDockerContainer.start();

            context.getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(
                    ADockerContainer.class, aDockerContainer);

            context.addApplicationListener(
                    (ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>)
                            contextClosedEvent ->
                                    aDockerContainer.stop());
        }
    }
}
```

And inject it into the test classes:

```
public class TestClass1 extends AbstractTestClass {
    
    @Autowired
    private ADockerContainer aDockerContainer;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("TestClass1 test " + aDockerContainer.getData());
    }
}

public class TestClass2 extends AbstractTestClass {
    
    @Autowired
    private ADockerContainer aDockerContainer;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("TestClass2 test " + aDockerContainer.getData());
    }
}
```

`ADockerContainer` class:

```
public class ADockerContainer {
    private UUID data;

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Start container");
        data = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stop container");
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data.toString();
    }
}
```

(Example) output:

```
Start container
TestClass1 test 56ead80b-ec34-4dd6-9c0d-d6f07a4eb0d8
TestClass2 test 56ead80b-ec34-4dd6-9c0d-d6f07a4eb0d8
Stop container
```